# undefined variable error in blade view

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I am currently working with Laravel 5.2, trying to display images on click
which I have currently stored in the **Storage** folder. I am trying to display these images in my blade view but every time it loads the page, it gets to an undefined variable exception.

**Controller**:

```
public function createemoji($action,$statusId)
{  
    $path = storage_path('app/public/images/'.$action.'.gif');

    /*$request=new storage();
    $request->comment=$path;
    $request->user_id=Auth::user()->id;
    $request->post_id=$statusId;
    $request->save();*/
    return redirect()->returnemoji()->with('file'->$path);

}

public function returnemoji($file)
{           
    return Image::get('$file')->response();
}
```

In my default view I tried using **count()** but everytime it loads the page, it gives me **Undefined variable**. How should I display it?

Answer (score 2):

Try to change this:

```
->with('file'->$path);
```

To this:

```
->with('file', $path);
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/views#passing-data-to-views

Comment: its still not getting displayed in the blade view,undefined variable it says.

Comment: You also need to remove the quotes around the file variable in this line: return Image::get($file)->response();

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to try the following:

Instead of:

```
return redirect()->returnemoji()->with('file'->$path);
```

Try this:

```
return redirect()->returnemoji($path);
```

And yes, remove the quotes from this:

```
return Image::get('$file')->response();
```

Answer (score 0):

With function takes two arguments key and value

You can use this

```
return redirect()->returnemoji()->with('file',$path);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this out:

Instead of:

```
return redirect()->returnemoji()->with('file'->$path);
```

Try this:

```
return $this->returnemoji($path);
```

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems.

1. Single quotes do not process variables, so instead of this

   ```
   return Image::get('$file')->response();
   ```

   You could do this

   ```
   return Image::get("$file")->response();
   ```

   or

   ```
   return Image::get("{$file}")->response();
   ```

   but none of this is necssary since you are just using the variable by itself without any additional formatting, so remove the quotes altogether

   ```
   return Image::get($file)->response();
   ```
2. The object operator `->` is used in object scope to access methods and properties of an object. Your function `returnemoji()` is not a method of `RedirectResponse` class which is what the [`redirect()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/helpers#method-redirect) helper method returns.
3. The `with()` method is not appropriate here, you just need to pass a parameter to a function like this

   ```
   return redirect()->returnemoji($path);
   ```

Optionally, I recommend following the [PSR2 code style standard](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-2-coding-style-guide.md) which includes camel cased variable names so `createemoji()` should be `createEmoji()`.  Also I think you can usually omit `response()` when returning most data types in Laravel as it will handle that automatically for you.